# Why can I find originalEvent but not event?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

In my handler for events I use the following function.

```
function handleThis(data) {
  console.log(data.event);
  console.log(data.originalEvent);
}
```

Instinctively, I'd expect both to exist. According to [some info I've found](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jquery-en/g-ELO7Hxwys) it was a bug long time ago but has been fixed slightly less long time ago.

What do I miss?

In this particular case, I'm obtaining the coordinates of a click event by `data.getX()` and `data.getY()` but the check for auxiliary keys needs to be done by `data.originalEvent.altKey`, which is discrepancy, which I know someone's going to ask me about. I want to be able to explain myself when the day comes. ("*It's just is that way...*" won't do, most likely, haha.)

Comment: How is the function triggered

Comment: @adeneo By me left-single-clicking with the rodent somewhere on the page. Or did you mean something other in particular?

Comment: Then post the event handler ?

Comment: Looks like the event in this case would be `data`.

Comment: @Teemu - It sure looks that way, if it's a regular event handler like [**this one**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q68Qb/)

Comment: @adeneo It's strange indeed. That's exactly what I'm doing. However, I failed to mention that I'm acting on an event for BingMaps and this is (...taking cover for all the pies and tomatoes thrown at me here...) *Microsoft.Maps.Events* thingy. I'm guessing the weirdification arises there. Put that as a reply instead of comment and I'll check it green, unless you've got some other hints.